# Unable to launch app on device

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to run a demo project to implement widgets, it compiles successfully but did not launch, also I did not find it installed in my phone.

I am following this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_widgets.htm

A also this tutorial https://github.com/TechIsFun/android-widget-example but getting the same problem.

My console shows

```
[2014-11-23 11:01:30 - WidgetExample] Performing sync
[2014-11-23 11:01:30 - WidgetExample] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2014-11-23 11:01:34 - WidgetExample] Uploading WidgetExample.apk onto device '1C9E_9E18_MicromaxA111'
[2014-11-23 11:01:34 - WidgetExample] Installing WidgetExample.apk...
[2014-11-23 11:01:37 - WidgetExample] Success!
[2014-11-23 11:01:37 - WidgetExample] \WidgetExample\bin\WidgetExample.apk installed on device
[2014-11-23 11:01:37 - WidgetExample] Done!
```

I think there is some problem with the manifest file ?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.widgetexample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver
        android:name="MyWidgetProvider"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Example Widget" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: 1- Try unplugging the device and plugging again; 2- Try restarting the device; 3- Try checking off the USB debugging option and then checking it ON back again. Please comment if these do not work.

Comment: Main launcher activity is missing in manifest.xml

Comment: please close the question if found your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your console message shows that your apk is isntalled sccuessfully on the device. Now the question is why it is not getting launched? 
To launch any application, it should have at least one activity with action as main and category as launcher.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

In your case, your application don't have any activity assoicated with it.
I think this is the casue why its not getting launched afer sccuessful installation. also thats why its not showing your application on application list.

As your application have only one widget hence it will show it under widgets list. Please check.

Hope it helps you.